# Change name of domain - what about SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, domain

How would SharePoint react to a change of domain name? Only domain name, the rest is the same?

I use SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 1):

This is not easy task from what i understand. You want to change the domain name for you sharepoint farm, correct?

- Moving SharePoint Server to different domain is not supported, you have to build the new farm on destination farm then migrate the database to new farm.

But if you are moving users to different domain then it will be different story.

Comment: The task is to change only name of domain, there won't be new domain, only name will change?

Comment: what mean by domain name change...is it from domaina to domainB?

Comment: no, I had on my mind to remane domain not change domain? sorry if I expressed vaguely

Comment: i am confused as i am not AD guy....what is difference between rename a domain name and chnage a domain. for me booth looks same

Comment: is similar like e.g. rename the name of server? machine is the same, only name changed. but how can react SharePoint to the same domain with other name?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE can you provide some references on this?

Comment: Again i am not AD guy, but looks like a domain change. you have to update the Server with new domain name, here is the actual problem occures, which upset the config db. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d3c5f5b8-5629-4a53-b141-2ed048a87e0e/moving-sharepoint-2010-to-a-new-domain

Comment: http://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2011/09/23/move-sharepoint-2010-server-to-another-domain/